# Touchscreen Netbook eOS 5.0 problem

Tags: release-juno, touchscreen

team - I´m surprised about the functionality and beauty of your operation system. Unfortunately I failed to fix the following screen-bug:
Whenever I started eOS 5.0 the screen shuts down after exately 19sec., I tried - rotation lock, energy saving off, automatic login etc. but nothing helps. I can turn the computer on again and after 19sec. the screen turns black again.
Only if I change the BIOS from "splash quite" to "nomodeset" the screen keeps stable with an awful resolution of course. Alternatively I can run the system as a life-system, the resolution is high and the screen stable, but that's not what I plan to do for the long go. 
I even failed in finding actual Intel Graphics drivers for eOS :-(

Thanx for helping hints!

Machine-DATA
PRO Intel Atom x5-Z8350 
GRA Intel HD Graphics (Cherry Trail)
MEM 2048 MB 
MON 11.6' 16:9, 1920 x 1080 Pixel 190 PPI, Capacitive, IPS